# Showing a DialogFragment throws "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" error

Tags: android, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, dialogfragment

## Problem

Hi, I'm creating an Android and iOS module for Titanium which has a sendLog method which sends some arbitrary JSON data to a server and returns an URL if it matches some predefined filters. The URL should be opened in a modal Dialog with a webview.

I've written native iOS and Android libraries and wrapped them as Titanium modules. On iOS everything works fine but on Android I can't open the Dialog (see error stack trace below). Right now there's one log message that always triggers the same webpage for testing purposes. On Android it just fails silently.

## Test case

```
var mupets = require("be.iminds.mupets");
mupets.initialize("wappr", "http://tocker.iminds.be:3000/log/report.json", 1, 100, 3);
var esmLog = { 
    bar: "foo"
};
mupets.sendLog("es-test-01",JSON.stringify(esmLog));
```

After this piece of code (after about 10 seconds max), the module should show a native dialog with the following webpage inside: http://tocker.iminds.be:3000/es/sheets/test-01/index.html

Instead, this is the error I get consistently:

## Logs

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1411)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1429)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:687)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:663)
at android.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:256)
at be.iminds.mupets_client_android.logging.plugins.OutHttp.getEsm(OutHttp.java:122)
at be.iminds.mupets_client_android.logging.plugins.OutHttp$1.success(OutHttp.java:78)
at be.iminds.mupets_client_android.HttpClient$1$1.onResponse(HttpClient.java:76)
at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:133)
at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here is the Android code that's causing the error:

```
Activity activity = (Activity) context;
                EsmDialogFragment esmDialogFragment = EsmDialogFragment.newInstance(new EsmDialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void submit(String type, JsonObject result) {
                        Mupets.sendLog(type, result);
                        esmShown = false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(JsonObject cancelled) {
                        super.onCancel(cancelled);
                        Mupets.sendLog("ESM_cancelled", cancelled);
                        esmShown = false;
                    }
                }, url, true);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Fragment prev = activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(EsmDialogFragment.ESM_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
                if (prev != null) {
                    transaction.remove(prev);
                }
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                Log.v(TAG, "Pre-show fragment");
                esmDialogFragment.show(transaction, EsmDialogFragment.ESM_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
                Log.v(TAG, "Post-show fragment");
```

Does Titanium either not allow the use of Fragments/or require you to call Dialog.show() at a specific point? The error talks about "...after onSaveInstanceState" but I don't see how I would call it before onSaveInstanceState if I'm not creating an activity and why the code works when I use it in a native Android app.

This is an Titanium example project with the module that should show the dialog after it opens:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0v77xd5gllv6kb3/testModule.zip?dl=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since dialogfragment does not have option to `commitAllowingStateLoss`, the simplest solution I used was to set a flag when onSaveInstance is called and reset it on `onCreate` and `onRestoreInstance`. Then before making a fragment transaction, check the flag to be sure its false. btw, this usually occurs in a asynchronous callback. The activity is already gone beyond onSaveInstance by the time background work has completed and callback has triggered.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a trivial problem, so there's no quick and easy fix that you can just copy/paste from an answer. The bottom line is that you will have to refactor some of your code.

You are trying to show a `DialogFragment` in response to an asynchronous operation - if that operation completes after `onSaveInstanceState`, the callback will try to show the dialog and induce an `IllegalStateException`.

The way to protect yourself from this issue is to not do UI stuff directly from callbacks. Instead, you need to hold off until you have a started or resumed `Activity` or `Fragment`, so that you can show the dialog safely.

An easy way to do this is to use sticky events, i.e. post a sticky event from your callback and subscribe for that type of sticky event in your UI component's `onResume` method.

If you don't want to use an event bus library, you can instead call your asynchronous method from a non-UI component that updates its internal state inside the callback, and then make the UI component check that state in `onResume`. If you use this approach, you need to be careful with managing your global state.

Comment: That are indeed the solutions I've found so far but they don't work for me. 2 problems occur: 1) I don't have direct access to the onResume method because the library is used in Appcelerator Titanium which has iets own subclasses of Activity and you use Javascript to program your views. 2) When I call this method directly instead of from a callback, it shows the same error.

Comment: I've made an alternative solution to DialogFragment, that can avoid this exception : https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/DialogShard

Answer (score 2):

I know this question already has a right answer but I want share my solution, to show DialogFragment you should override `show()` method of it and call `commitAllowingStateLoss()` on `Transaction` object. Here is example in Kotlin:

```
override fun show(manager: FragmentManager?, tag: String?) {
        try {
            val ft = manager?.beginTransaction()
            ft?.add(this, tag)
            ft?.commitAllowingStateLoss()
        } catch (ignored: IllegalStateException) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: What about internal flags `mDismissed = false;` and `mShownByMe = true;` which seems does not called?

Answer (score 2):

With reference to @Dennis comment, i have override the method show and it works.

```
@Override
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(this, TAG);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue and solved this issue by overriding show() in DialogFragment extended class.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
        try {
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(this, tag);
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d("ABSDIALOGFRAG", "Exception", e);
        }
    }
}
```